# Android Studio 3 beta 2 ClassNotFound in kotlin unit tests

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I am using Android Studio 3.0 beta 2, converted an existing project to gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta2

When I try to run an existing unit test written in kotlin I get 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/other/domain/CollectionItem'

The test itself is very simple:

```
import org.junit.Test

import org.junit.Assert.*

class CollectionViewModelTest {
    @Test
    fun getItemsWithManyItemsWillReturnCollectionItemViewModels() {
        val collectionItems = listOf(CollectionItem(42, "Item1", CollectionItemType.COLLECTION, ""), CollectionItem(43, "Item2", CollectionItemType.COLLECTION, ""), CollectionItem(44, "Item3", CollectionItemType.COLLECTION, ""))
        val collection = Collection(45, "Home", "Home collection", collectionItems, 42)
        val collectionViewModel = CollectionViewModel(collection)

        assertTrue(collectionViewModel.items.first().isFirst)
        assertFalse(collectionViewModel.items.first().isLast)

        assertFalse(collectionViewModel.items[1].isFirst)
        assertFalse(collectionViewModel.items[1].isLast)

        assertTrue(collectionViewModel.items.last().isLast)
        assertFalse(collectionViewModel.items.last().isFirst)
    }
}
```

It works when I run it from the terminal using ./gradlew

Any ideas why this can happen?

**Edit:**

This seems to happen only when the test requires classes from other library projects.

In this case `CollectionItem` is part of another library in the same project and it's included in the gradle file via implementation project(':domain')

**Edit**

It might also be worth mentioning that `domain` module is pure java

**Edit**

Figured out the problem is when the library (`domain`) has classes written in kotlin, those classes will throw NoClassDefFoundError in unit test's only.